# Tkinter, how to return results from class method to new frame

Tags: python-3.x, oop, tkinter

This is my first complex Tkinter App, and it takes in user inputs and generates an instance of an imported class.  What's the best way to pass the details into another frame?  I'm using a lambda to run "generate_more_stuff" which creates an instance of the imported class, and then opens the new frame "parent.show_frame("Calculate")".  I just can't figure out how to pass the results to the Calculate Class.  I think I'm getting confused by the multiple references to self.

```
from tkinter import *
import os


class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.my_stuff = stuff + " " + stuff

    def display(self):
        print(self.my_stuff)
    


class MainApplication(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.home_frame = HomeFrame(self)
        self.home_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,10), pady=10, sticky="nsew")

class HomeFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.frames = {}
        for sub_frame in (Enter, Calculate):
            page_name = sub_frame.__name__
            frame = sub_frame(parent=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=20, pady=20)
        self.show_frame("Enter")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class Enter(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # self.controller = controller
        self.grid(padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        label_stuff = Label(self, text="Enter stuff").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=0)
        self.stuff_entry = Entry(self)
        self.stuff_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=0, pady=0)

        button1 = Button(self, text="Generate", command=lambda:[self.generate_more_stuff(), parent.show_frame("Calculate")])
        button1.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5, padx=5, sticky="E")
        

    def generate_more_stuff(self):
        stuff = self.stuff_entry.get()
        self.instance = MyClass(stuff)        
        self.instance.display() # Results shown on command line


class Calculate(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = Label(self, text="I want to show my results here.")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApplication()
    app.mainloop()
```

This appears to be a common pattern for Tkinter apps on StackOverflow.  I've tried to simplify the code as much as possible without obscuring whats happening too much.

Comment: It is better to post code related to `MyClass`.

Comment: I've added a sample MyClass and the code should now run.  In reality MyClass is a large program but I just want it's results passing to the Calculate frame.  I think I'm confused by the self from MyClass and the self from the Tkinter app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show the result inside `Calculate` class, I would suggest the following changes:

- add `get()` in `MyClass` to return `self.my_stuff`
- modify `HomeFrame.show_frame()` to return the raised frame
- do all the required stuff inside `Enter.generate_more_stuff()` instead of using `lambda`
- add `update_result()` in `Calculate` class to update the label

Below is the modified code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import os


class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.my_stuff = stuff + " " + stuff

    def display(self):
        print(self.my_stuff)

    # added function to return my_stuff
    def get(self):
        return self.my_stuff


class MainApplication(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.home_frame = HomeFrame(self)
        self.home_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,10), pady=10, sticky="nsew")

class HomeFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        self.frames = {}
        for sub_frame in (Enter, Calculate):
            page_name = sub_frame.__name__
            frame = sub_frame(parent=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=20, pady=20)
        self.show_frame("Enter")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()
        return frame   # return the raised frame


class Enter(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # self.controller = controller
        self.grid(padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

        label_stuff = Label(self, text="Enter stuff").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=0)
        self.stuff_entry = Entry(self)
        self.stuff_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=0, pady=0)

        button1 = Button(self, text="Generate", command=self.generate_more_stuff) # just call generate_more_stuff instead of using lambda
        button1.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5, padx=5, sticky="E")


    def generate_more_stuff(self):
        stuff = self.stuff_entry.get()
        self.instance = MyClass(stuff)
        self.instance.display() # Results shown on command line

        # show the Calculate frame
        frame = self.master.show_frame("Calculate")
        # update the label inside Calculate frame
        frame.update_result(self.instance.get())


class Calculate(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # change label to self.label
        self.label = Label(self, text="I want to show my results here.")
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=10, pady=10)

    # added function to update self.label
    def update_result(self, value):
        self.label.config(text=value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApplication()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.  I was fixated on doing it through the Tkinter app.